# pymongo 3.8 not work with mondob 4 and python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

Connect to mongodb 4 server with pymongo 3.8 but get serverselection timeout error
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: IP:host: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. 
I could not connect at first then changed to master host. 
After that the connection problem fixed. However, I still cannot CRUD or list collections. It throws 
   `OperationFailure: Authentication failed.`